# Button is not immedeatelly working after postback in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer-11

I have dynamically added update panel with textbox search, button handeling enter key and with gridview on my page. When I search by pressing the key (postback in update panel proceed), edit buttons clicks don't work in IE 11 and even doesn't work right click at button (for example when I want to run element inspector). Only after second click it works.

EDIT:

I'll try to describe code

Search bar is located in nav element and gridview is generated below.

Textbox has OnKeypress: `if ( event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13 ) {$("#SEARCHBUTTONID")[0].click()}`

Button handles on click search function which cause databind.

Edit buttons in grid generates normally onClick event: `javascript:__doPostBack('IDOFGRID_CommandEdit','IDOFRECORD')`

I found when I call only `$("#SEARCHBUTTONID")[0].click()` from console, editbutton's first click does not work too.
But strange is that the editbutton is not even clickable (when i want open by right click menu and click inspect element, somewhere else it works)

Comment: ok - and where is your code?

Comment: code i really complex so I can only add small parts of code I'll try

Comment: maybe that is the main problem. try to simplify your code to find your mistakes. but nobody here at SO will help you when you don't post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So main problem was that after `BUTTON.click();` event JS focused somewhere else. So when someon has bad functionality after click, try `ELEMENT.focus();` at wanted element - after that, elements are clickable again in gridview.